How do I retrieve my lost password?
I bought $3800 of Bitcoin in 2017 and I've lost my password, the salesperson who sold me the product had a stroke and is in a wheelchair. She incapacitated. Without a decent contact us form how do find out who took over the portfolio?
Need help.
Thanks,
Billy Joe Cordova.

let me reflect your question back to be sure I understand it and to make the situation clear to you too.

You gave $3800 to someone on the understanding they would use it to buy some things for you.

That person took the money but never gave you those things

You never saw the things yourself, never saw any evidence that they existed.

You were happy for the other person to look after the things on your behalf

You never asked the other person to give you "your" things

The other person never gave you the things. Never gave you the purchase receipt they obtained when they bought the things.

The other person is now no longer available

You hope that random strangers on the other side of the world might know where the things are.


The truth is, there is no global organisation that keeps track of every thing one person owes another person. When you lend a neighbour your lawnmower, no official knows about that, nobody far away writes down that your neighbour owes you a lawnmower. The only person who knows where the lawnmower is stored is your neighbour, not some government department, not some international organisation.
Bitcoin is a mostly-anonymous peer-to-peer system of electronic cash (not accounts, not portfolios) without any need for trusted intermediaries. There is no organisation in charge of Bitcoin. If you don't have electronic cash in your own electronic wallet in your own computer, you don't really possess that cash.
From what you wrote, I'd guess you have no prospect of getting that cash.

If you believe you are the victim of fraud, the normal way to deal with that is to report it to your local police.
If you believe some person is not keeping up their side of a financial agreement, even if no fault of their own, the normal way to handle that is by consulting a lawyer about a lawsuit.
